# Java объявление классов

Tags: java, ооп, объекты

Можно ли в java объявить класс прямо в методе?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Это будет локальный класс(внутренний):

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        method();
    }

    private static void method() {
        String name = "name";

        class A {
            void print() { 
                System.out.println(name); 
            }
        }

        new A().print();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да.

```
public void validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber1) {
    final int numberLength = 10;
    class PhoneNumber {
        String formattedPhoneNumber = null;
        PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
            String currentNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
              regularExpression, "");
            if (currentNumber.length() == numberLength)
                formattedPhoneNumber = currentNumber;
            else
                formattedPhoneNumber = null;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return formattedPhoneNumber;
        }

        public void printOriginalNumbers() {
            System.out.println("Original numbers are " + phoneNumber1 +
                " and " + phoneNumber2);
        }
    }

    PhoneNumber myNumber1 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);

    myNumber1.printOriginalNumbers();
}
```

Только зачем? Код становится совсем нечитабельным